# linq 3 table joins not materialising third table into a list

Tags: c#, linq, join

I'm joining three tables in linq, there is a one to one relationship between the first 2 tables then a one to many between the second and third, how can I materialise all the rows from the third table into a list ?, here's what I have so far but its only returning the first match from the 3rd table

```
var query = await (from contracts in DbContext.CHPContracts
                               join organisation in DbContext.Organisations on contracts.END_USER_ORG equals organisation.End_User_Org into organisation_joined
                               where request.ContractRefRequests.Contains(contracts.CONTRACT_REF)
                               from oj in organisation_joined.DefaultIfEmpty()

                               select new UserDto
                               {
                                   Email = oj.CHPContacts.FirstOrDefault().Email,
                                   FirstName = oj.CHPContacts.FirstOrDefault().FirstName,
                                   LastName = oj.CHPContacts.FirstOrDefault().LastName,
                                   ID = oj.CHPContacts.FirstOrDefault().ID,
                                   SMS = oj.CHPContacts.FirstOrDefault().Mobile,
                                   Status = oj.CHPContacts.FirstOrDefault().Status,
                                   UserID = "",
                                   UserRole = "",
                                   OrgID = oj.CHPContacts.FirstOrDefault().OrgId,
                                   OrganisationName = oj.OrganisationName,
                                   End_User_Org = oj.End_User_Org
                               }).ToListAsync();
```

obviously its the .FirstOrDefault() bit that's causing that behaviour, but I cant figure out how to get the 3rd table records into a list, anyone help me out ?

Comment: any examples you could provide ?

Comment: I have used navigation between tables 2 and 3 but EF didnt create one between tables 1 and 2 despite creating the relationship in the DB, I think its because the relationship is based on a string column not an integer

Comment: navigation property -> oj.CHPContacts.FirstOrDefault().Mobile

Comment: as I explained, EF didn't create one, despite the fact I created one in the DB, I think its because the relationship is on a string column not an integer column

Comment: the relationship between organisation and CHPContacts is based on an integer column, so the navigation property is available

Comment: the contract reference doesn't exist in the organisation table, look at what I'm  searching for in the WHERE clause

Comment: CHPContacts are the contacts associated with the organisation which is specified in the joined table (oj)

Comment: organisations and contacts have a navigation property, contracts and organisations don't

Comment: All these comments don't make any sense to me. Only a class model does.

Comment: no idea what you're talking about, I only asked for advice materialising a joined table to a list, which I solved myself eventually

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out in the end

```
var query = await (from contracts in DbContext.CHPContracts
                               join organisation in DbContext.Organisations on contracts.END_USER_ORG equals organisation.End_User_Org into organisation_joined
                               where request.ContractRefRequests.Contains(contracts.CONTRACT_REF)
                               from oj in organisation_joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               from contacts in oj.CHPContacts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               select new UserDto
                               {
                                   Email = contacts.Email,
                                   FirstName = contacts.FirstName,
                                   LastName = contacts.LastName,
                                   ID = contacts.ID,
                                   SMS = contacts.Mobile,
                                   Status = contacts.Status,
                                   UserID = "",
                                   UserRole = "",
                                   OrgID = contacts.OrgId,
                                   OrganisationName = oj.OrganisationName,
                                   End_User_Org = oj.End_User_Org
                               }).ToListAsync();
```